# Preload images from mysql with jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, preload

I need some help, I can not seem to figure out how to preload images for my next button on an image viewer that I built. I am grabbing image source from mysql database and iterating through them each time the next button is pressed. How can I preload these? Here is my code for next button:

```
$("#next").click(function(){
            $(h).empty();
            var p = <?php echo json_encode($results); ?>;
            var start = $("#intabdiv img").attr("class");
            var next = p[($.inArray(start, p) + 1) % p.length];
            //Checking the ID of thumbnail pictures and determining the id here
            var hinext = "../php/admin/portfolio/before/"+next;
            $("#intabdiv img").attr('src',hinext);
            $("#intabdiv img").attr('class',next);
            //Centering image on screen
            var h = $("#intabdiv img").width() + 70;
            //ww is defined beforehand and is the windows width.
            var total = ww - (h / 2);
            $(".popupbox").css("margin-left", total);
        });
```

Comment: What does the inside of "var p" look like? Kinda hard to guess right now.

Comment: It is a simple array looks something like this (image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg). thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not enjoying your code. Try putting in a few line breaks every now and again (before comments is usually a good place).

Anyway, this is a good way to preload images using jquery:

```
$('<img />').attr('src', 'http://url/to/image.jpg');
```

The first part creates an image element (but doesn't add it to the DOM)

```
$('<img />')
```

The next part sets the SRC and therefore loads the image resource in the browser:

```
attr('src', 'http://url/to/image.jpg');
```

Comment: but my image results are in an array and placed in var p. How would I preload those. That was my question. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much! All I had to do was add an .each loop to loop through the array and I put this function inside. Thanksss!